# delegate is not respond

Tags: ios, delegation, respondstoselector

I am trying to use delegation between two Viewcontrollers, but unfortunately my delegate doesn´t get fired. I hope somebody can help me fix the problem. I have a ViewContoller called MapBackgroundViewController and one called MapsViewController. The MapsViewController should be informed if the SegmentedControl of the MapsBackgroundViewController changes.
(I actually try to implement something like the maps app on iPhone with patrial curl)

Here is part of my code:

MapBackgroundViewController.h

```
@protocol ChangeMapTyp <NSObject>
@required
- (void)segmentedControllChangedMapType:(MKMapType) type ;
@end


@interface MapBackgroundViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
MKMapType mapType;
id < ChangeMapTyp> delegate;

}


@property IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;

@property MKMapType mapType;

@property(strong)id delegate;

- (IBAction)segmentedControllChanged:(id)sender;
```

MapBackgroundViewController.m

```
@interface MapBackgroundViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapBackgroundViewController
@synthesize segmentedControl, mapType, delegate;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[self setDelegate:self];

NSLog(@"%@",self.delegate);

}


- (IBAction)segmentedControllChanged:(id)sender {

if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
}else if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
} else if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
 //   [self.delegate setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];
    mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
}


//Is anyone listening

NSLog(@"%@",self.delegate);

if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(segmentedControllChangedMapType:)])
{
    //send the delegate function with the amount entered by the user
    [self.delegate segmentedControllChangedMapType:mapType];
}

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

MapsViewController.h

```
#import "MapBackgroundViewController.h"

@class MapBackgroundViewController;

@interface MapsViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate,
UISearchBarDelegate,  ChangeMapTyp >{
 IBOutlet MKMapView *map;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *map;


@end
```

MapsViewController.m  (the below method for some reason gets never called)

```
 - (void)segmentedControllChangedMapType: (MKMapType) type{
    map.mapType = type;
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `MapBackgroundViewController` you have set the `delegate` property to `self`, so the delegate is `self` - (`MapBackgroundViewController`) so when you perform the check `if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(segmentedControllChangedMapType:)])` it returns `NO`, because `self.delegate` (which is `self`, which is `MapBackgroundViewController`), does not implement this method. If you want your `MapsViewController` to be the delegate, in your `MapBackgroundViewController` you must have an instance of `MapsViewController` (called `myMapsViewController` for example) and then set the `self.delegate = myMapsViewController`.

Comment: +1 that and never ever use `strong`/`retain` on a delegate property as you will render a retain cycle when doing so.

Comment: ah ok, thank you. I see the problem. I really appreciate your help.
 But if I try to do something like :
     MapsViewController myMapsViewController = [MapsViewController alloc]init];
I have to #import my MapsViewController in the MapBackgroundViewController.h (or .m). BUT, if I #import it, I get the error message : "cannot find protocol declaration for changeMapTyp" in the MapsViewController.h .
Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: BTW, I can´t use alloc init, because i don´t want a new Map. I want to change the mapType of my old one?

Comment: import it in the .m file and you won't get the error. I can't quite understand why you need the MapsViewController? Can you explain?

Comment: ok, thank you. 
well i want to implement some like the map app on iphone.
two Viewcontrollers:  first one with the map, and second on can be accessed with a partial curl to change the mapType.
the problem is that i don´t get it work to change the maptype of the MapsViewController, if the SegmentedControl of the MapBackgroundViewController changes. I hope I could explain myself better this time. 
thank you for taking your time to help me

Comment: So, in your MapsViewController, where you initialize your MapBackgroundViewController: `MapBackgroundViewController *myCtrl = [[MapBackgroundViewController alloc] init....]; myCtrl.delegate = self; //self would be MapsViewController` then present/show the MapBackgroundViewController

Comment: aaahhh ok, you are so right, this makes it a lot easier than i thought. 
so what i did now (because i am using storyboard) is this in the MapsViewController:

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)showMapBackground{
    MapBackgroundViewController *myCtrl = [[MapBackgroundViewController alloc] init]; 
    myCtrl.delegate = self;
}

unfortunately if i check/print the self.delegate in viewDidload from the MapBackgroundViewController it is still NULL???? I can´t explain this to me, because how you mentioned I set it to the MapsViewController in the prepareForSegue method.

Comment: BTW, if I set a Breakpoint in the prepareForSegue Method, it stop there. so the Methods gets called.

Comment: finally, I got everything working. For all those who want to know how, here is how I did the prepareForSegue:

    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
   
       if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"showMapBackground"]) {
           MapBackgroundViewController *myCtrl = segue.destinationViewController ;
           myCtrl.delegate = self;
       }
   }

the rest of the code, should be the same as above.

special thanks to graver